# Собрать js в build в правильной последовательности

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, gulp

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему

Есть js-проект. Исходник находятся в каталоге src, продакшн-код в каталоге build. При этом для сборки использую gulp

[Вот](http://i.yapx.ru/ETde.png) мои исходные js-файлы
После сборки результирующий файл выглядит приблизительно [так](http://i.yapx.ru/ETdf.png)

Проблема в том, что строчка

```
var tests=angular.module('tests',['ngMaterial'])
```

расположена в конце файла. А должна быть в начале потому что в этой строке объявляется сам модуль. Весь остальной код лишь дополняет его.

Научите пожалуйста как собрать проект правильно. То есть чтобы сначала в результирующий js-файл записался код объявления модуля, а потом уже всё остальное.

Привожу код gulpfile.js:

```
'use strict';

var gulp            = require('gulp');
var cssmin          = require('gulp-cssmin');
var rename              = require('gulp-rename');
var jsmin               = require('gulp-jsmin');
var concat          = require('gulp-concat');
var clean               = require('clean');
var del                   = require('del');
var mainBowerFiles  = require('gulp-main-bower-files');
var imagemin        = require('gulp-imagemin');
var browserSync     = require('browser-sync').create();


gulp.task('clean', function() {
  return del.sync(['build/*', 'libs/*.*']);
});

gulp.task('cssmin', function () {
  gulp.src(['src/libs/**/*.css', 'src/css/*.css'])
    .pipe(cssmin())
    .pipe(concat('styles.min.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'));
});

gulp.task('main-bower-files', function() {
  return gulp.src('./bower.json')
    .pipe(mainBowerFiles())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/libs'));
});

gulp.task('libsmin', function () {
  gulp.src('src/libs/**/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('libs.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'));
});

gulp.task('jsmin', function () {
  gulp.src('src/js/*.js')
    .pipe(jsmin())
    .pipe(concat('scripts.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'));
});

gulp.task('imagesReplace', function() {
  return gulp.src(['src/images/*'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/images'));
});

gulp.task('html', function() {
  return gulp.src(['src/*.html'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(['src/*.html'], ['html', browserSync.reload]);
  gulp.watch(['src/libs/**/*.js'], ['libsmin', browserSync.reload]);
  gulp.watch(['src/js/**/*.js'], ['jsmin', browserSync.reload]);
  gulp.watch(['src/images/**/*'], ['imagesReplace', browserSync.reload]);
  gulp.watch(['src/css/*.css'], ['cssmin', browserSync.reload]);
});


gulp.task('default', ['clean', 'cssmin', 'main-bower-files', 'libsmin', 'jsmin', 'imagesReplace', 'html', 'watch']);
```

Если важно, то структура всего проекта выглядит [так](http://i.yapx.ru/ETdi.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы задать порядок, можно поставить модуль [gulp-order](https://github.com/sirlantis/gulp-order)

Например:

```
gulp.task('jsmin', function () {
  gulp.src('src/js/*.js')
      .pipe(order([
          "vendor/app.js",
          "vendor/app2.js",
          "vendor/**/*.js",
          "app/**/*.js",
          "vendor/last.js",
      ]))
    .pipe(jsmin())
    .pipe(concat('scripts.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'));
});
```